# Find a number $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{355213}$ such that $x = 2 \pmod {71}$ and $x = 13 \pmod {5003}$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

As the title says, my problem is this:

Find a number $x \in \mathbb{Z}/{355213}\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x = 2 \mod 71$ and $x = 13 \mod 5003$.

I know that $71\cdot 5003 = 355213$. I also know that $71$ and $5003$ are prime.

I solved this with programming ($x=235154$), but I naively searched through all possibilities. I'd like to know how to solve this without programming.

Comment: Ignore the $\mathbb Z_n$ stuff and solve it with the chinese remainder theorem. Then see what it is equal to modulo n.

Comment: Thanks @DavidP! This is for a cryptography class and we have not yet covered the Chinese Remainder Theorem. But as it is popping up a lot, could you link me to somewhere that teaches this theorem? The Wikipedia page was a bit beyond my comprehension.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ru7mWZJlRQg

Comment: @TylerDurden you might find the [cut the knot page](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/chinese.shtml) a bit more accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation shows that $x = 2 + 71n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The second equation is that $x = 13 + 5003m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So we must find integers *n* and *m* such that $2 + 71n = 13 + 5003m$, or $71n - 5003m = 11$.

The [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) can be used to find them.

Start by dividing $-5003$ by $71$: $$-5003 = (-71)*71+38$$
Then continue by dividing each quotient by remainder:
\begin{align}
71 &= 1*38+33 \\
38&=1*33+5 \\
33&=6*5+3 \\
5&=1*3+2 \\
3&=1*2+1 \\
\end{align}

Now go back up the chain to write $gcd(-5003,71)=1$ in terms of $-5003$ and $71$:
\begin{align}
1&=3-1*2 \\
&=3-1*(5-1*3) \\
&=2*3-5 \\
&=2*(33-6*5)-5 \\
&=2*33-13*5 \\
&=2*33 - 13*(38-33) \\
&=15*33-13*38 \\
&=15*(71-38)-13*38 \\
&=15*71-28*38 \\
&=15*71-28*(-5003+71*71) \\
&=-1973*71-28*(-5003)\\
\end{align}

Multiply both sides of the equation $1 = -1973*71 - 28*(-5003)$ by $11$ to get $11 = -21703*71-308*(-5003)$. So $n=-21703$ is one solution, which gives $x = 2 + 71(-21703) = -1 540 911$  in $\mathbb Z_{355213}$ which is equivalent to your solution of $235154$.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight_Club_2

This method is called a [Continued Fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).

$$  5003/71 \approx 70.4647  $$
$$ 70.4647, \; 2.1515, \; 6.5999, \; 1.6666, \; 1.4999, 2.0000   $$

$$  
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
 & & 70 & & 2 & & 6 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 &  \\
\frac{0}{1} & \frac{1}{0} & & \frac{70}{1} &  &  \frac{141}{2} & &  \frac{916}{13}  & & \frac{1057}{15} & &  \frac{1973}{28} & &   \frac{5003}{71}   
\end{array}
$$

$$ 5003 \cdot 28 - 1973 \cdot 71 = 1  $$