# Continued fractions: convergence of fraction expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, continued-fractions

Using the notation $[a_0,a_1,a_2,...]$ for the continued fraction

$$
 a_0 + \dfrac{1}{a_1 + \dfrac{1}{a_2 + \dfrac{1}{...}}}
$$

where $a_0 ∈ \mathbb Z$ and $a_i ∈ \mathbb N$ for all $i>0$

Question: Consider the continued fraction expansion
$$
[1,0,1,1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,...,1,2n,1,...]
$$

and let $p_i$ and $q_i$ denote the numerators and denominators (respectively) of its convergents. Prove that

$$
p_{3n} = p_{3n-1} + p_{3n-2},  q_{3n} = q_{3n-1}+q_{3n-2}
$$
$$
p_{3n+1} = 2np_{3n} + p_{3n−1},  q_{3n+1} = 2nq_{3n} +q_{3n−1}
$$
$$
p_{3n+2} = p_{3n+1} + p_{3n},  q_{3n+2} = q_{3n+1} +q_{3n}
$$

for $n=1,2,....$

---

As I understand it, the numerators are $[1,0,1,1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,...,1,2n,1,...]$ while the denominator's are $[1,1,...]$. But I do not know what exactly is meant with "of its convergence".

I am also uncertain how to proceed with proving the above mentioned questions, but I do believe it relates to the "fundamental recurrence formulas" as I read a bit about in the following wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction

Merry Christmas and happy new year.

Comment: The convergents of a continued fraction are like partial sums of an infinite sum; to borrow your notation, the convergents of your continued fraction would be $a_0,a_0+\cfrac1{a_1},a_0+\cfrac1{a_1+\cfrac1{a_2}},\dots$.

Comment: I found the following document about continued fractions.

Comment: I found the following document about continued fractions: http://www.math.illinois.edu/~ajh/453.spring11/nt-notes6.pdf

I still need to understand exactly how to apply these and where they ordinate from, but do you think I understand the assignment correctly, by saying this is what i need to understand and apply?

Comment: If the usual three-term recurrence for the numerators and denominators of the $n$-th convergent is in that document, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you don't know how to take the sequence of $a_i$ and produce the sequence of ordinary fractions called "convergents," often written $\frac{p_i}{q_i}.$  I have written out a few examples, sometimes for finite CF, sometimes for infinite.

Oh, the traditional way to start things is with
$$ \frac{p_0}{q_0} =  \frac{a_0}{1}.  $$
In order for all the formulas to work out, I draw in two pretend convergents at the left edge, giving
$$ \frac{p_{-2}}{q_{-2}} =  \frac{0}{1},  $$
$$ \frac{p_{-1}}{q_{-1}} =  \frac{1}{0},  $$
$$ \frac{p_0}{q_0} =  \frac{a_0}{1}.  $$
Note that the $1/0$ is fake, it is just a convenience, not a genuine fraction.

You have written the sequence of $a_i$ incorrectly, there may not be a zero as $a_1.$ Here is one  correct possibility. If you change $a_0,$ all the denominators stay the same, each numerator changes by a fixed multiple of the relevant denominator.

I can recommend Hardy and Wright, chapter 10.

$$  
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 4 & & 1 & & 1 & & 6 &   \\
\frac{0}{1} & \frac{1}{0} & & \frac{1}{1} &  &  \frac{2}{1} & &  \frac{5}{3}  & & \frac{7}{4} & &  \frac{12}{7} & &   \frac{55}{32}  & &   \frac{67}{39}  & &   \frac{122}{71}   & &   \frac{799}{465}  \\
\end{array}
$$

[Solving Diophantine Equation - odd Periods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393247/solving-diophantine-equation-odd-periods/1394771#1394771)

[Problem in a Pell equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594284/problem-in-a-pell-equation/1594291#1594291)

[Find a number $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{355213}$ such that $x = 2 \pmod {71}$ and $x = 13 \pmod {5003}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935141/find-a-number-x-in-mathbbz-355213-such-that-x-2-pmod-71-and-x/1935157#1935157)

[Convergents as solutions for Pell's equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949263/convergents-as-solutions-for-pells-equation/1949471#1949471)

[Is there a simpler way to find an inverse of a congruence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028083/is-there-a-simpler-way-to-find-an-inverse-of-a-congruence/2028096#2028096)

Here are the basic rules from wikipedia. They use $h_n/k_n$ rather than $p_n/ q_n,$ but they keep the $a_n.$

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe you are correct. I have also read that the convergence of a infinite continued fraction as similar or exactly as you wrote above.

Comment: I will look at it in a bit and give feedback as to if i understand it or not. Thank you for the examples (links) above.